# "Try using a name with fewer characters or with no punctuation marks." - But the characters look OK

Tags: finder

"Try using a name with fewer characters
or with no punctuation marks."

This seems to happen sometimes with filenames that look okay to me.
If I retype the exact same filename, it is accepted.

Thus, I think there must be an invisible, non-accepted character in the name that I have copied from inside the pdf (the title).

However, if I paste this into the SUBLIME text editor, I see no unexpected characters.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you use a shorter name?

Comment: Try `ls "*Oligo*" | od -xc` to see the exact characters in the filename.  What program is telling you it can't use that file?

Comment: Do you want to save the file on the interal drive or on another one? If you paste into Sublime and then copy again there, does the name in the clipboard then work as a name?

Comment: @red_menace I will have to wait until this situation happens again to test in detail, but I was able to type any length name. I was able to type, then copy and paste, but not from the pdf and also not from my OCR to clipboard app (text sniper)

Comment: @WGroleau "ls: *Oligo*: No such file or directory", because I haven't been able to name the file yet. I was able to type it in by hand, but often a pdf will save with a non-sensical name and I need to name it from the pdf title. edit: If I could apply a command like "od" to the contents of the clipboard, that might show something

Comment: @nohillside It's the internal drive. Same behavior on an external drive

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was the newline character, i replaced it with space and the issue went away. Hope this helps.